# How to specify method default argument using define_method?

Tags: ruby

`define_method` could be used to define methods:

```
define_method(:m) do |a|
end
```

which is equivalent to the following:

```
def m(a)
end
```

However, what is the equivalent form of the following using `define_method`:

```
def m(a=false)
end
```

*Note that I'd need to be able to call `m()` without giving any argument.*

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This actually just works like you would expect in Ruby 1.9!

```
define_method :m do |a = false|
end
```

If you need 1.8 compatibility, but you don't necessarily need a closure to define your method with, consider using `class_eval` with a string argument and a regular call to `def`:

```
class_eval <<-EVAL
  def #{"m"}(a = false)
  end
EVAL
```

Otherwise follow the suggestion in the thread that philippe linked to. Example:

```
define_method :m do |*args|
  a = args.first
end
```

Comment: I really like Ruby. "Can I do X?", "Yes, X works just as you'd hope!", "Horray!"

Answer (score 5):

This is currently not possible [due to the yacc parser](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/msg/2c3c0722133427f8). 
[This thread on Ruby-forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/121058) proposes several solutions.

```
class A
     define_method(:hello) do | name, *opt_greeting|
        option = opt_greeting.first || Hash.new
        greeting = option[:greeting] || "hello"
        puts greeting+" "+name
     end
end


a = A.new
a.hello "barbara"
a.hello "Mrs Jones", :greeting => "Good Morning"
```